# Check if user input anything before pressing enter

Tags: java

I am doing a basic java console application and I want to check if the user provided any input before pressing enter. I'm using the Scanner class to get the input. Right now all I get is that the application just waits for input whenever I press enter without typing in anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go in a loop that waits for enter. If the user presses enter, check for input, if no input is provided, continue the loop. If input was provided, break from the loop.

If you want the mechanism to be non-locking, you need a separate thread.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = null;
while ( true )
{
   s = input.nextLine();
   if( !s.equals("\\n") ) 
      break;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what is needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = input.nextLine();
if(s.equals("")) System.out.println("You didn't insert any text");
else System.out.println("You insert some text");
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing as the op's solution, it just prints out whether the user entered something before the question or not.

Comment: I just give him the idea of how to check if the user inserts something or not