# Is there any equivalent of getch() from C++ in Java?

Tags: java, c++, console-application

Is there any equivalent to C++’s `getch()` in Java? That is a function that moves the control forward as soon as a keyboard key is pressed, and also stores the character pressed.

I would like to use that function in a console app.

Comment: Should be noted `getch` isn't a standard C++ function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `getch()` function equivalent in java. But since you are not the first one who is asking about it, there are some solutions available:

- [Equivalent function to C's "_getch()" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864076/equivalent-function-to-cs-getch-in-java)
- http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=471633

I think nothing has changed since then - I mean, no new getch() alike functions were added to Java.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `getch()` function  equivalent in java.

You have  to create a GUI  and attach the `Event` Listener's to them .

EDIT:[How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: What about, if I want to acheive this in `console` ?

Comment: No,you asked **as soon as a button is pressed...**

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear, now it's **keyboard key**

Comment: You can do it with Scanner class.

Comment: I know, but that'll require the enter key to be pressed after typing the character, and I want a single key to be pressed not an ENTER along with it and move to the next statement of program.

Comment: Something like this ??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817202/check-if-user-input-anything-before-pressing-enter

Answer (score 2):

You can use casting and get a character value from the console directly.

```
public class TestConsole
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        // Read the char
        char ch = (char) System.in.read();

        System.out.print("\n You pressed: " + ch);
    }
}
```

It's working. See this demo online. http://ideone.com/RZ6vhK

Comment: But that'll require the enter key to be pressed after typing the character, and I want a single key to be pressed not an ENTER along with it and move to the next statement of program.

Comment: Edited. Now it works. Added an online execution to see yourself.